# How to set a customField in Polarion using Java in IformExtension

Tags: java, polarion

In Polarion, I have created an java class using IFormExtension .
I would like to set a customfield. When i do it i get an error

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Modifications are prohibited in read only transaction.

how to set a write transction and do workitem.save(),
Thank you

Comment: Some source code would be helpful? Which instruction caused the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You should run your modification code within the write transaction. Something like this:

```
TransactionalExecutor.executeInWriteTransaction(transaction -> updateWorkItem())
```